# How to speed a function that filters out elements from a large array

Tags: javascript, node.js

In a node.js based program, I'm trying to filter out elements from an array of 500,000+ paths in size, like: `paths = ['C:/test/file.txt', 'C:/python/', ...]`

### Code

Basically, what the code is doing is this:

- If `itemTypeToSearch` has `"files"` => update the `paths` array by filtering out all the paths that are "directories" (leave only files)
- If `itemTypeToSearch` has `"folders"` => update the `paths` array by filtering out all the paths that are "files" (leave only directories)

---

```
import fs from 'fs'
...
itemTypeToSearch: ["files"]
...

console.time("time it took:")
  // IF ONLY 1 TYPE SELECTED, FILTER IT OUT
  if (this.itemTypeToSearch.length == 1 && this.itemTypeToSearch.includes("files")) {
    paths = paths.filter(element => { 
      return fs.statSync(element).isFile()
    })
  } 
  else if (this.itemTypeToSearch.length == 1 && this.itemTypeToSearch.includes("folders")) {
    paths = paths.filter(element => { 
      return fs.statSync(element).isDirectory()
    })
  }     
console.timeEnd("time it took:")
```

This filtering operation takes about `4 seconds` to process an array of 100,000 paths.

After that I'm turning the filtered array into an array of objects for further use in another function:

`[{path: 'C:/test/file.txt'}, {path: 'C:/python/python.exe'}, ...]`

### Questions

How do I make it faster? (like much much faster)

Should I convert it into the array of objects **first**? Will that allow me to filter items out faster?

Comment: If you are looking for directories vs file types, is there a reason you are not just checking if the path ends in a known file extension?

Comment: @epascarello I haven't tried this approach. You think it might be faster than `fs.statSync(element).isFile()` ? I have [node-mime](https://github.com/broofa/node-mime) nodule imported which knows all the common file types, but I'm not sure how would I use that in this case. Get all the types: `commonFileTypes` and then check if `commonFileTypes` includes the last part of the `element` (which I get with a `regex` expression) ?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to filter out elements from such a large array any faster when using `fs.statSync(element).isDirectory()` or `fs.statSync(element).isFile()`.

Perhaps it can be done faster by checking if a string ends with a known extension (which means it's a file), as @epascarello suggested in the comments.

Maybe someone will post a solution which does that.

#### Workaround

In my case it's 10 times faster to do all the operations on the non-filtered array (though it will have about 2x the amount of paths)

And then when program displays the final results (which is limited to like 100 items) filter it out at this step which will take just a few milliseconds